# statement to query table but limit returned rows based on distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm curious if a single SQL statement can do something like this?

I have a table of of something like this:

```
name, manufacturer, value
```

I'd like to list the `top x` number of each manufacturer based on a query of other criteria.

For example,

```
SELECT name, manufacturer, value 
from table 
where value<100 
order by manufacturer
```

But ideally I'd like, say, to only return the `first 10` from each manufacturer.  I am aware I can write a script to parse a returned table and ignore records after the `first 10`, but is there a way to build a query that would do it automatically?

Comment: What is your criteria for those 10 records?  In other words, specify the sort order of the values after criteria.  Is it the top 10 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work for you:

```
SET @Manufacturer = '';
SET @RowNum = 1;

SELECT  Name,
        Manufacturer,
        Value
FROM    (   SELECT  @RowNum := IF(@Manufacturer = Manufacturer, @RowNum + 1, 1) AS RowNumber,
                    Manufacturer,
                    Name,
                    Value,
                    @Manufacturer := Manufacturer
            FROM    Item
            ORDER BY Manufacturer, Name DESC
        ) Item
 WHERE  RowNumber <= 10
```

This returns the first 10 ordered by name, you would need to change the order by clause in the subquery to change how the query decides which are the "first" 10 records for each manufacturer.

Comment: Interesting.  So it's safe to assume these types of queries are best handled by the script and not SQL itself?  Is the code above compatible with MySQL?

Comment: Yes this is compatible with MySQL.I tested it using this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6050/9). It entirely depends on individual situations as to whether it is best handled within SQL or within your program. I am not sure how well MySQL performs with functions like this as I work with SQL-Server, but with SQL Server I'd do it within SQL itself. Why process more rows than necessary, and why send more data to your application than necessary. But ultimately there is no substitute for testing. Pick the solution that works best for your specific situation.

Comment: It just ocurred to me, could you also do it by having the inner query with a limit 10?  like select distinct mfg on the outside, feed that to an inner query which uses the selected mfg and pulls 10?  I haven't done much work in SQL with nested SELECTs

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,manufacturer,value
FROM YOURTABLE 
LIMIT 0,x;
```

Comment: The above will just limit total records.  I want x from each distinct manufacturer.